# Android: How do I load External JSON data via JSON or JSONP in webview

Tags: android, android-webview, android-scripting

I have an application with WebView

I tried to load external data via Ajax (Get) but it failed with no errors, tried JSONP and failed with no errors too.

Now here are more info:

When my External Source is an IP-Based like **http: //192.168.0**......../path/data  Things work fine for both JSON and JSONP

but when the external source is a Domain  **http:// subdomain.mydomain.com**   Things doesn't work (it never completes loading)

I even tried to specify the JSONP source as

```
<script src="http://subdomain.mydomain.com/path/?callback=callbackFunc"></script>
```

but still this script never completes loading

Please notice that the external URL works normally in web-browser and even on my PC (using the JSONP method).

I believe it's either Cross-Domain policy problem which I don't know how to fix.

or a DNS problem (Which I don't know how to fix too).

or there might be a better way for loading external data inside WebView in android

Comment: Two things to check. First, do you have `INTERNET` permission? Second, do you enable Javascript in Webview?

Comment: @xandy yes I mentioned in my question that when the external source is IP, things work normally but when it's a domain name it doesn't . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the answer to the problem,

The UserAgent of my Android was being blocked on my server for the specified path,

The IP I was using was a network IP, while the domain was another server . .

now it's fixed..